# Labeling the x-axes in a plot arbitrarily

Tags: plotting

I have a List of data and plotted them but i want scales on the x-axis shown as `[10^-4 , 10^-2 , 0.02 , 0.04 , 0.06 , 0.08 ]` instead of 1 through ,say,9 (i.e. number of data shown in the axes). can anybody know how do i that?

```
ListPlot[Table[m^2,[m,10^-4,0.09,0.01]]
```

Very Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Mathematica will not want to show the .0001 tick value (it falls too near the origin), for this labeling problem it is better to use a frame than to try to relabel the axes.

```
ListPlot[Table[{m, m^2}, {m, .0001, 0.09, 0.01}],
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {Join[{.0001, .01}, Range[.02, .08, .02]], None}}]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 3):

Using the option [`DataRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange.html) will basically do what you want

```
ListPlot[Table[m^2, {m, 10^-4, 0.09, 0.01}], DataRange -> {10^-4, 0.09}]
```

[image]

However, to get literally the labels you specified, you will need to also specify custom [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html)

Comment: very thanks. this is what i wanted.

Comment: @Ali184 Please consider accepting the answer(by clicking on ✓ right symbol).